# How to have access to mutliple views in one tab of the tab bar in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, tabbar

I am having 3 tab in the tab bar.I would like to have an access when we we click the first tab it need load the Activity 1<->Activity 2 <->Activity 3 <->Activity 4.How to get this,any examples on this will be helpful. I have tried all other examples with single activity but when I try to call the multiple activities no luck on it.Thanks

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You want to load 4 different activities in 4 tabs?

Comment: I would like to load 4 different activities in the first tab only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I got from your question is that your requirement is to have `Sub-Activity` inside a `Single Tab`. You can use `ActivityGroup` for that, but now it is `deprecated` you can use `Fragments Compatibility Package` which works from `1.6` `version` too. So, here is an example for that [`FragmentTabs.java`](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentTabs.html)

Comment: I need your help for Having multiple activity in a SingleTab please help me for that.